# Optimizing this solution: Longest consecutive distinct sequence of integers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Sample input:

```
5
1
2
1
3
1
```

First number = # of members in the set, N

Following N numbers = ID's of the members

I'd have to find the size of the longest consecutive sequence of distinct integers in the set. In this instance, it'd be the sequence of {2, 1, 3}, so the output would be 3.

My brute force solution would be to generate a sliding window that shrinks in size by 1 every iteration. The initial size is the size of the input. So, for the sample input, it'd evaluate {1, 2, 1, 3, 1} first, if set is not all unique, then decrease the window to 4, and evaluate {1, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 3, 1}. Keep going until you found a set that's unique.

For one, I believe this algorithm would be O(N^2) time. So, how might I optimize this?

Comment: Your concept of sliding window seems odd. If applying correctly, it should be O(N) instead, the direction is correct so I think you should take a relook at sliding window technique.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your concept of sliding window seems odd"?

Comment: It is not done correctly, you better check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash table for an `O(N)` solution. Simply put, keep track of the last index of each unique element and the last time a repetition happens. The maximum between these two variables at each index is how far back you can go at that index without repeating.

For sake of completeness here is a straightforward and (hopefully) well commented python implementation:

```python
def longestDistinctSequence(iterable):

    res = 0
    # store the indices of each unique element
    hashmap = {}
    # keep track of how back you can go before you run into a repetition
    last_repeat = 0

    # loop through each index and item
    for index, item in enumerate(iterable):

        # how back you can go before you can run into a repetition is the max of:
        #     1. The last occurence of this element (zero if this is first instance)
        #     2. The last_repeat of the last iteration
        last_repeat = max(hashmap.get(item, 0), last_repeat)

        # calculate the global maximum
        res = max(res, index - last_repeat + 1)

        # update the hashmap to reflect the repetition of this element
        hashmap[item] = index + 1

    return res
```

Comment: Consider adding `<!-- language: lang-python -->` above your code, so that it'll be formatted as python.

Comment: @DillonDavis whoa that's a thing?!?!? Edited and thanks :)

Comment: Also, not that its particularly better or worse, but Python provides `defaultdict` in the `collections` module as a replacement for `dict` when you need the behavior `hashmap.get(item, 0)` achieves.

Comment: @DillonDavis thanks for the suggestion! I think `.get()` is just a little more readable than `defaultdict(int)` especially when OP seems to be a java person.

Comment: Hi, I would like a little bit of clarification. "Simply put, keep track of the last index of each unique element and the last time a repetition happens. The maximum between these two variables at each index is how far back you can go at that index without repeating." Can you elaborate on the reasoning behind this a little?

Comment: The comments in the code do a better job of explaning.  Imagine your iterating foward over the string, at each index u find how far backwards you have to go to run into the first repetition. That would be O(N^2) if we brute force it, but by keeping track of how far back u went the last time and the last time the current index repeats, you can figure out how far back you go in O(1) (its the max of the two), and doing that N times gets u O(N)

Comment: The correctness of that assertion (that it's the max) is pretty simple - for each index when you iterate backwards you'll run into either a repeat of itself (stored in the hash table) or a repeat of something else (what the previous iteration ran into) and how far back you can go is the furthest foward of those two repeats

Comment: Hello, I will look at this again in a couple of days; thank you

Comment: @J.Doe any progress?